# Using auto generated (ie random) IDs in HTML forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm creating a form from various complex controls that I have built as Backbone views. Understandably I want to reliably link the labels to the `<input>` elements, which I am doing with the normal `for` attribute.

However, sometimes I need to use the same control multiple times. I am using data attributes to drive the form, so I do not need the `id` attribute for my own use, and can use classes to identify each control.

Therefore, I am considering whether it makes sense to generate random ids, just to link the `<label>` and `<input>` together? This seems a really bad idea, but I am unsure there is a better one?

I can't just put the `<input>` inside the `<label>`, as they have to be separate from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing bad in auto-generating IDs. If they have not to be human- (== developer) readable, you can go crazy there. Create a simple function, that spits out unique strings, and there you go:

```
function generateId() {
    return 'GENERATED_ID_' + (++generateId.counter);
}
generateId.counter = 0;

id = generateId();
html = '<label for="'+id+'">Foo</label> <input id="'+id+'">';
```

Nothing bad happening here.

(Of course, if you *could* nest the input in the label, that would be a wee bit nicer.)

Comment: Thanks, combined with use of the Backbone `cid`, this could work nicely!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `cid` attribute of the Backbone view. This is already unique. Probably then override `_.template` in a base view to always include this (to save passing in each time).